# Dash the stroke of UIBezierPath without using the CAShapeLayer and animate this stroke

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uibezierpath, cabasicanimation

`UIBezierPath` only get dashed when used inside `drawRect()` method in `UIView` like so:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        let  path = UIBezierPath()
        let  p0 = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.minX, y: self.bounds.midY)
        path.move(to: p0)
        let  p1 = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.maxX, y: self.bounds.midY)
        path.addLine(to: p1)

        let  dashes: [ CGFloat ] = [ 0.0, 16.0 ]
        path.setLineDash(dashes, count: dashes.count, phase: 0.0)
        path.lineWidth = 8.0
        path.lineCapStyle = .round
        UIColor.red.set()
        path.stroke()
    }
```

[image]

If I want to animate this line stroke, I'll be needing to use `CAShapeLayer` like so

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        let  path = UIBezierPath()
        let  p0 = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.minX, y: self.bounds.midY)
        path.move(to: p0)
        let  p1 = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.maxX, y: self.bounds.midY)
        path.addLine(to: p1)

        let  dashes: [ CGFloat ] = [ 0.0, 16.0 ]
        path.setLineDash(dashes, count: dashes.count, phase: 0.0)
        path.lineWidth = 8.0
        path.lineCapStyle = .round
        UIColor.red.set()
        path.stroke()

        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.path = path.cgPath
        layer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.lineWidth = 3
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        layer.lineJoin = kCALineCapButt
        self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        animateStroke(layer: layer)
    }

    func animateStroke(layer:CAShapeLayer)
    {
        let pathAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        pathAnimation.duration = 10
        pathAnimation.fromValue = 0
        pathAnimation.toValue = 1
        pathAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
        layer.add(pathAnimation, forKey: "strokeEnd")
    }
```

The Black line of the `CAShapeLayer` got animated.

[image]

What I need is, to add dashed UIBezierpath to CAShapeLayer, so that I can animate it.

Note: I do not want to use CAShapeLayer's `lineDashPattern` method as I'm appending multiple paths some need to be dashed and some not.

Comment: use multiple CAshapelayers if you do not want to share attributes across paths.

Comment: That's what I'm using currently, but since I have multiple CAShapelayers representing my path, I have difficulties in adjusting the duration of each path, the animation of the complete path is not very smooth @JoshHomann

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not invoke animations from [`draw(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw). The `draw(_:)` is for rendering a single frame.

You say you don't want to use `lineDashPattern`, but I personally would, using a different shape layer for each pattern. So, for example, here is an animation, stroking one path with no dash pattern, stroking the other with dash pattern, and just triggering the second upon the completion of the first:

```
struct Stroke {
    let start: CGPoint
    let end: CGPoint
    let lineDashPattern: [NSNumber]?

    var length: CGFloat {
        return hypot(start.x - end.x, start.y - end.y)
    }
}

class CustomView: UIView {

    private var strokes: [Stroke]?
    private var strokeIndex = 0
    private let strokeSpeed = 200.0

    func startAnimation() {
        strokes = [
            Stroke(start: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.midY),
                   end: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY),
                   lineDashPattern: nil),
            Stroke(start: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY),
                   end: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY),
                   lineDashPattern: [0, 16])
        ]
        strokeIndex = 0

        animateStroke()
    }

    private func animateStroke() {
        guard let strokes = strokes, strokeIndex < strokes.count else { return }

        let stroke = strokes[strokeIndex]

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = strokes[strokeIndex].lineDashPattern
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 8
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: stroke.start)
        path.addLine(to: stroke.end)

        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = 1
        animation.duration = Double(stroke.length) / strokeSpeed
        animation.delegate = self
        shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    }

}

extension CustomView: CAAnimationDelegate {
    func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        guard flag else { return }

        strokeIndex += 1
        animateStroke()
    }
}
```

[image]

If you really want to use the `draw(_:)` approach, you wouldn't use `CABasicAnimation`, but instead would probably use a `CADisplayLink`, repeatedly calling `setNeedsDisplay()`, and having a `draw(_:)` method that renders the view depending upon how much time has elapsed. But `draw(_:)` renders a single frame of the animation and should not initiate any CoreAnimation calls.

---

If you really don't want to use shape layers, you can use the aforementioned `CADisplayLink` to update the percent complete based upon the elapsed time and desired duration, and `draw(_:)` only strokes as many of the individual paths as appropriate for any given moment in time:

```
struct Stroke {
    let start: CGPoint
    let end: CGPoint
    let length: CGFloat                // in this case, because we're going call this a lot, let's make this stored property
    let lineDashPattern: [CGFloat]?

    init(start: CGPoint, end: CGPoint, lineDashPattern: [CGFloat]?) {
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.lineDashPattern = lineDashPattern
        self.length = hypot(start.x - end.x, start.y - end.y)
    }
}

class CustomView: UIView {

    private var strokes: [Stroke]?
    private let duration: CGFloat = 3.0
    private var start: CFTimeInterval?
    private var percentComplete: CGFloat?
    private var totalLength: CGFloat?

    func startAnimation() {
        strokes = [
            Stroke(start: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.midY),
                   end: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY),
                   lineDashPattern: nil),
            Stroke(start: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY),
                   end: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY),
                   lineDashPattern: [0, 16])
        ]
        totalLength = strokes?.reduce(0.0) { $0 + $1.length }

        start = CACurrentMediaTime()
        let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(handleDisplayLink(_:)))
        displayLink.add(to: .main, forMode: .commonModes)
    }

    @objc func handleDisplayLink(_ displayLink: CADisplayLink) {
        percentComplete = min(1.0, CGFloat(CACurrentMediaTime() - start!) / duration)
        if percentComplete! >= 1.0 {
            displayLink.invalidate()
            percentComplete = 1
        }

        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    // Note, no animation is in the following routine. This just stroke your series of paths
    // until the total percent of the stroked path equals `percentComplete`. The animation is
    // achieved above, by updating `percentComplete` and calling `setNeedsDisplay`. This method
    // only draws a single frame of the animation.

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let totalLength = totalLength,
            let strokes = strokes,
            strokes.count > 0,
            let percentComplete = percentComplete else { return }

        UIColor.red.setStroke()

        // Don't get lost in the weeds here; the idea is to simply stroke my paths until the
        // percent of the lengths of all of the stroked paths reaches `percentComplete`. Modify
        // the below code to match whatever model you use for all of your stroked paths.

        var lengthSoFar: CGFloat = 0
        var percentSoFar: CGFloat = 0
        var strokeIndex = 0
        while lengthSoFar / totalLength < percentComplete && strokeIndex < strokes.count {
            let stroke = strokes[strokeIndex]
            let endLength = lengthSoFar + stroke.length
            let endPercent = endLength / totalLength
            let percentOfThisStroke = (percentComplete - percentSoFar) / (endPercent - percentSoFar)
            var end: CGPoint
            if percentOfThisStroke < 1 {
                let angle = atan2(stroke.end.y - stroke.start.y, stroke.end.x - stroke.start.x)
                let distance = stroke.length * percentOfThisStroke
                end = CGPoint(x: stroke.start.x + distance * cos(angle),
                              y: stroke.start.y + distance * sin(angle))
            } else {
                end = stroke.end
            }
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            if let pattern = stroke.lineDashPattern {
                path.setLineDash(pattern, count: pattern.count, phase: 0)
            }
            path.lineWidth = 8
            path.lineCapStyle = .round
            path.move(to: stroke.start)
            path.addLine(to: end)
            path.stroke()

            strokeIndex += 1
            lengthSoFar = endLength
            percentSoFar = endPercent
        }
    }
}
```

This achieves the identical effect as the first code snippet, though likely it isn't going to be anywhere near as efficient.